# Convert PHP query to AJAX Query and Update views with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following script which i am trying to convert to AJAX:

HTML:

```
                <form action="php/additem.php" method="post" class="form-inline pull-right">
                    <h4>'.$row['itemName'].'</h4><input id="itemname" type="hidden" name="itemName" value="'.$row['itemName'].'">
                    <h3>$'.$price.'</h3><input id="price" type="hidden" name="pricetotal" value="'.$price.'">
                    <img src="../wholesale/img/sourdough.jpg" class="img-reponsive">
                    <p>'.$row['description'].'</p><input id="description" type="hidden" name="description" value="'.$row['description'].'">
                    <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputAmount">Qty</label>
                    <div class="input-group">
                    <input id="qty" type="number" name="qty" class="form-control" id="exampleInputAmount" placeholder="How Many?">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" id="additem" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
                </form>
```

PHP:

```
session_start();
include('db_config.php');

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$itemname = $_POST['itemName'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$price = $_POST['pricetotal'] * $qty;
$id = $_SESSION['customer_id'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders (deliveryDate, customerId, itemName, qty, price) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($date, $id, $itemname, $qty, $price));
```

Now this script will be adding from ITEM table to ORDERS table.
In the actual page that displays the data i have 2 sections and an ajax query that retrieves data from both tables.

The Ajax that retrieves and displays the data from both tables:
This is NOT the additem AJAX:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.date-picker').change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: 'php/getproduct.php',
                 data: {dateorderpicker: $('.date-picker').val()},
                 dataType: 'JSON',
                 success: function(data)
                 {
                    $("#cartrow").html(data.result_1);
                    $("#otheritems").html(data.result_2);
                 }
             });
         });
     });
```

My question is do i need to re-retrieve and display from these two tables again using my additem script? So the result will, item will move dynamically to orders section?

I hope that makes sense.
Thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

```
php function ()
{
$var = $_POST['fieldname'];
//enter your insert code here.....
if($query == success)
    {
       return "success";
    }
}
```

On ajax call the

php function

```
 or
```

the .php file where you have mentioned the php function to insert the data.

finally display the response on ajax

thats it.

Comment: My main issue is how would i write the ajax query? and pass the variables to the php file?

And do i need to then retrieve the cart and items list again so the update is dynamic? For example when i add the item from items list it will go to the orders table and display without page refresh?

Comment: ok I got what you need but its all together a lot need some time to update

Comment: let me know if you need any additional information as the php that does the initial retrieving using ajax is a little complex

Answer (score 0):

field 1
            
            field 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").on(submit,function(){
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test2.php',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: "html",

            success: function(response)
            {
               alert(response);
            }
        })
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

action page

$var1 = $_POST['aaa'];
$var2 = $_POST['bbb'];

echo $var1 . "
";
echo $var2;
return "success";

this is how it should work but actually i was usng on a framework